# How can I read JSON file and generate dynamic page using jQuery based on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, electron

i am new to this node and json things and I have someproblems getting data out of JSON. 
This is my code

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let questsRawData = fs.readFileSync('quests-db.json');
let quests = JSON.parse(questsRawData);

for (var i = 0; i < quests.length; i++) {
  console.log(quests[i].title);
}
```

when i run this in node I am getting results as expected in terminal but in browser I am getting this msg in console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at showNeg.js:241
    at XMLHttpRequest.onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandler (showNeg.js:311)
```

also if i try to append results with jQuery to the DOM like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < quests.length; i++) {
  $(body).append('<p>' + quests[i].title + '</p>);
}
```

I am getting this error in terminal

```
C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\Test\main.js:9
  $(body).append('<p>' + quests[i].title + '</p>');
  ^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I am trying make desktop application with electron and I was thinking to use JSON as local db.

Thank you

Comment: `$ is not defined` is because you have not included jquery in your project. For the other error see if that is a valid json. Check it with some online json validator

Comment: I included jquery before main.js in html page

Comment: `main.js` is typically not linked by the html page (aka the `renderer` process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install your jquery as dependency

`npm install --save jquery`

And then at your index.html add this script.

```
  <head>
    <script>
      window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    </script>
    ....
```

And `createBrowerWindow` with `nodeIntegration` as true at your main.js.

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

And to read json file just this will be enough.

```
let quests = require('./quests-db.json');
```

One more thing. Json Object can't be iterable. For your case. you need to use like this.

```
for (const key in quests) {
  console.log(quests[key]);
}
...
$(body).append('<p>' + quests[key].title + '</p>);
```